# How to use extractall in Pandas and get a new column with the extracted strings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a data frame of 15 columns from a csv file. I am trying to remove one part of the text of a column and create a new column containing that information on each row. Each row of 'phospho' should have only one match to my demands on extractall. Now, I am trying to add the result to my data frame but I get the error:

> **TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index**

The dataset has two column with names, and 6 columns with values (like 65.98, for ex).

> Ex:
>
> accession sequence modification phospho CON_1 CON_2 CON_3 LIF1
>   LIF2 LIF3 P18767 [R].GAAQNIIPASTGAAK.[A]
>   1xTMT6plex[K15];1xTMT6plex[N-Term] 1xPhospho [S3(98.3)]

Here is the freaking code:

```
    a = pmap1['phospho'].str.extractall(r'([STEHRYD]\d*)')
    pmap1['phosphosites'] = a
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give some examples of what is in pmap1["phospho"]?

Answer (score 4):

I created `pmap1` using the following sample data:

```
pmap1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 'S34T44X', 1 ], [ 'E23H78Y', 2 ],
    [ 'R49Y81Z', 3 ], [ 'D20U23X', 4 ]], columns=['phospho', 'nn'])
```

When you extract all matches:

```
a = pmap1['phospho'].str.extractall(r'([STEHRYD]\d*)')
```

the result is:

```
           0
  match     
0 0      S34
  1      T44
1 0      E23
  1      H78
  2        Y
2 0      R49
  1      Y81
3 0      D20
```

Note that:

- The result is of **DataFrame** type (with a single column named `0`).
- It contains **eight** rows. So it is not clear to which row insert
  particular matches.
- The index is actually a **MultiIndex** with 2 levels:

  - The first (unnamed) level is the index of the source row,
  - The second level (named *match*) contains the number of
    match within the current row.

E.g. in row with index `0` there were founde 2 matches:

- `S34` - No 0,
- `T44` - No 1.

So you can not directly save `a` as a new column of `pmap1`,
e.g. because `pmap1` contains "ordinary" index and
`a` is a **MultiIndex**, incompatible with the index of `pmap1`.
And just this is written in the error message.

If you want somehow "add" `a` to `pmap1`, you can e.g. "break" each match
as a **separate** column the following way:

```
a2 = a.unstack()
```

Gives the result:

```
         0          
match    0    1    2
0      S34  T44  NaN
1      E23  H78    Y
2      R49  Y81  NaN
3      D20  NaN  NaN
```

where *columns* are *MultiIndex*, so to drop the first
level if it, run:

```
a2.columns = a2.columns.droplevel()
```

The result is:

```
match    0    1    2
0      S34  T44  NaN
1      E23  H78    Y
2      R49  Y81  NaN
3      D20  NaN  NaN
```

Then you can perform the actual join, executing:

```
pmap1.join(a2)
```

The result is:

```
   phospho  nn    0    1    2
0  S34T44X   1  S34  T44  NaN
1  E23H78Y   2  E23  H78    Y
2  R49Y81Z   3  R49  Y81  NaN
3  D20U23X   4  D20  NaN  NaN
```

If you are unhappy about numbers as column names, you can change them as
you wish.

If you are unhappy about *NaN* values for "missing" matches
(for rows where less matches have been found compared to other rows),
add `.fillna('')` to the last instruction.

## Edit

There is a shorter solution:
After you created `a`, you can do the whole rest of processing
with a **single** instruction:

```
pmap1.join(a[0].unstack()).fillna('')
```

Comment: it doesn't work and I don't know why, because I don't get an error message, but when I print pmap1, nothing has changed. (I edited my question to make it clearer - I don't get a multindex, since each row only has one match to my extractall).

Comment: If I try the longer way you suggested, and go directly to join (skipping unstack and drop), then I get this error: ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names. Why would "a" not have the same index name as pmap1?!

Comment: A good description concerning the structure of MultiIndex in the result of *extractall* is contained in the documentation concerning *extractall*. Read it. Another hint: Print results of each intermediate step. It should clarify the issue.